# Trying to add a logo in my navigation

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav

I'll be honest, I'm probably missing something. What I'm trying to do with Bootstrap 3 is have a navigation that looks like this:

http://s24.postimg.org/a8bo7btol/Untitled.png

Now I have a basic structure of my HTML and the main issue is when I shrink my browser to roughly 700px wide, the main navigation stays on the top, the second navigation ends up underneath my main navigation (basically - my width was exceeded and everything falls down).

[image]

My image is 374 x 45.

Here is the non-bootstrap CSS:

```
body {
    margin-top: 125px;
}
.nav {
    margin-top: 28px;
}
```

Here is my HTML...

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <!-- You'll want to use a responsive image option so this logo looks good on devices - I recommend using something like retina.js (do a quick Google search for it and you'll find it) -->
          <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand logo-nav"><img src="images/icon.png"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar">
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

I'm at my wits end here... What am I missing?

Comment: Ideally, it should stay on the same line as long as possible, then collapse into the nav button.

Comment: What option would I be able to use that would allow me to keep the size of the image, that would keep the integrity of the size? (if that is an option that is)

Comment: codehorse - that article was excellent and very informative. I think I've got some ideas involving modifying the logo when it shrinks that actually works in the short testing I've conducted.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your external CSS with this...

```
body {
 margin-top: 125px;
}    
.logo-nav {
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
.logo-nav img{
  width:254px;
  height: auto;
}
```

This will make things work. You can control the space above logo with padding just make sure it does nor exceed total 50 px(total padding + calculated height of logo). In that case either you have decrease the width of logo or increase height of navbar. You can say thanks by accepting as correct answer.

Comment: Hi - I appreciate your help! However, the end result was the same. Adding the CSS you provided left me in the exact same predicament. However, tt may be on my end, I'll double check. Just didn't want to leave you hanging (sorry, had something come up in personal life).